# Tkinter doesn't want to work when using discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, discord, discord.py

So my problem is that the tkinter window doesn't appear when I'm using the discord.py API. But when I do ctrl+c to exit out the tkinter window it automatically appears, I think there's a conflict with client.run(TOKEN) because when I take that line out it works, but then my application doesn't do anything.

```
from tkinter import *
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord import Game

TOKEN = ""
BOT_PREFIX = "!"
client = Bot(command_prefix=BOT_PREFIX)

root = Tk()
root.title("NinjaBoT Discord Client")
root.resizable(0, 0)
root.configure(bg="black")
root.geometry("630x520")
labelframe2 = LabelFrame(root)
labelframe2.config(bg="black", padx=5, pady=10)
labelframe2.grid(row=1, column=3)
labelframe3 = LabelFrame(root)
labelframe3.config(bg="black", padx=5, pady=10)
labelframe3.grid(row=1, column=0)
labelframe = LabelFrame(labelframe3)
labelframe.config(bg="black", padx=5, pady=10)
labelframe.grid(row=2, column=0)
label = Label(root, text="NinjaBoT Discord")
label.config(bg="black", fg="white")
label.config(font=("Courier", 30))
label.grid(row=0)
label1 = Label(labelframe2, text="::USERS::")
label1.config(bg="black", fg="white")
label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
txtscroll = Text(labelframe3)
txtuserlist = Text(labelframe2)
txtmessage = Text(labelframe)

@client.event 
async def on_message(message):
    txtscroll.insert(END, "#" + str(message.channel) + ":" + " " + str(message.author) + ":" + " " + message.content + "\n")
    x = message.server.members
    for users in x:
        txtuserlist.insert(END, str(users.name) + "\n")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(game=Game(name="GUI"))
    txtscroll.insert(END, 'Logged in as' + "\n")
    txtscroll.insert(END, client.user.name + "\n")
    txtscroll.insert(END, client.user.id + "\n")
    txtscroll.insert(END, '-----------------------' + "\n")

scrollbar = Scrollbar(labelframe3)
scrollbar.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="ns")
txtscroll.config(width=60, height=20, bg="black", fg="white")
txtscroll.grid(row=1, pady=10, sticky=W)
scrollbar.config(bg="black", command=txtscroll.yview)
txtscroll.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

txtmessage.config(width=49, height=1)
txtmessage.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)

b = Button(labelframe, text="SEND",fg="white", command="send")
b.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5)

txtuserlist.config(width=10, height=23)
txtuserlist.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

client.run(TOKEN)
root.mainloop()
```

is there a better way to use client.run(TOKEN) so that this would work? I think is conflicting with root.mainloop()

Comment: ```.run()``` and ```.mainloop()``` would need to be run in different threads or processes. They both halt the program so the next line will never run until, like you said, either the tkinter window was closed or the discord bot has logged out. IMO it's a little strange to have discord and TKinter in the same file.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not that familiar with Tkinter, but when you run the line `client.run(TOKEN)`, it blocks the code until the bot stops working, essentially not reaching the next line.

You probably want to run `root.mainloop()` asyncly before you run the bot.
You can do that by putting that line in an async function:

```
async def open_window():
    root.mainloop()
```

And then adding it to the event loop:

```
client.loop.create_task(open_window())
client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried the code you posted and now the tkinter window is showing but my application doesn't work, it doesn't connect to the server.

Comment: the issue is that `root.mainloop` is not an async function, and will therefore block the async eventloop when run; so the discord.py code (along with anything else trying to run in the eventloop) will still be unable to run until the tkinter window is closed.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:
just run bot in another thread:
here is an example

```py
import threading
import discord
from tkinter import * 



client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

def run():
  bot.run("bot token")

def an():
    t = threading.Thread(target=run)
    t.start()#run the "run" function on another thread
root = Tk()             
 
root.geometry('100x100')
 
# Create a Button
btn = Button(root, text = 'Run', bd = '5',
                          command = an) 
btn.pack(side = 'top')   
 
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `root = Tk()` should be `root = tkinter.Tk()` ?

[https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_gui_programming.htm#:~:text=Tkinter%20is%20the%20standard%20GUI,to%20the%20Tk%20GUI%20toolkit.&text=Import%20the%20Tkinter%20module](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_gui_programming.htm#:%7E:text=Tkinter%20is%20the%20standard%20GUI,to%20the%20Tk%20GUI%20toolkit.&text=Import%20the%20Tkinter%20module).

Answer (score 0):

Just try to do:

`import tkinter`

Instead of

`from tkinter import *`